# How to get keyboard inputs and write letters in screen?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-input

I am a students who want to make a program to get keyboard inputs and write letters in the screen. But I don't know how. Which language that I could get inputs and write? I could use python, and also can use c and c++ a little bit.

Comment: In which language , do you find  yourself comfortable? python,c or c++? any of them can be useful to display user entered data on screen.

Comment: Well, since I have used python most, I want to use python if possible.